# What math predicted the eclipse of Betelgeuse?

Tags: astronomy, celestial-mechanics, eclipse

It's amazing that scientists can predict something as small as last weeks eclipse of Betelgeuse.  The general relativity aspects are quite specialized.  Can someone point me to the math involved in such a prediction?  I'd love to see an actual example of the math.

Comment: I think the [Einstein–Infeld–Hoffmann equations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein–Infeld–Hoffmann_equations) are used for asteroid trajectory calculations in the solar system.

Comment: @Ghoster do you know of an actual example of it being used, in something like the eclipse?

Comment: No. I just remember reading somewhere years ago that NASA used these equations for trajectories.

Comment: I [found](https://ntrs.nasa.gov/api/citations/19710017134/downloads/19710017134.pdf) an old NASA paper from the 1970’s about this.

Comment: @Ghoster That looks really interesting.  Thanks.  This whole astrophysics thing started for me a eight years ago when I wrote the novel "My Brother Chuck" (you can find it on Amazon) in which the narrator is an amateur stargazer and spends his evenings calculating the trans-lunar path of the Apollo missions using his slide rule.  "I was able to calculate and plot the entire translunar phase predicted for Apollo 11 in fifteen minute increments for the entire voyage from leaving Earth’s orbit to entering the Moon’s orbit."  At the end of the novel he starts his PhD thesis.